# How to Calculate Entropy Changes at Non-Standard Conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy

I am trying to calculate the values of $\Delta H$ and $T\Delta S$ for the reaction taking place at $\pu{800 ^\circ C}$

$$
\ce{CO2 + H2O + 2CH4 -> 3CO + 5H2}
$$

I calculated $\Delta H$ to be $\pu{\approx 480 kJ mol^{-1}}$ using Hess’ Law, i.e., by taking the reactants down to $\pu{ 25  ^\circ C}$ and calculating the enthalpy change, performing the reaction at standard conditions, and then taking the products back up to $\pu{800 ^\circ C}$.

However, I am having trouble with $T\Delta S$. Can I take the same approach as I did for the enthalpy change, taking the reactants/products between $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$-$\pu{800 ^\circ C}$ and calculating the entropy change at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$?  Then multiplying by the temperature in Kelvin?

I tried using the **Shomate equation** expression below for the reactants/products (taken from NIST), where A-G are Shomate equation coefficients; however, I’m not getting the correct answer of $\pu{\approx -80 kJ mol^{-1}}$, so unsure if this is the correct approach:

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta S = &A \ln{(T_2-T_1)} + B(T_2-T_1) + \dfrac{C}{2}(T_2^2-T_1^2)\\ &+ \dfrac{D}{3}(T_2^3-T_1^3) - \dfrac{E}{2(T_2^2-T_1^2)} + G
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: As you can evaluate integral  Cp.dT for  enthalpy, you can do the same for Cp.dT/T for entropy.

Comment: Are you using absolute temperatures in your entropy calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe applying the Shomate equation incorrectly:

$$
\ln{T_2} - \ln{T_1} = \ln{\dfrac{T_2}{T_1}}
$$

$$
\dfrac{1}{T_2^2} - \dfrac{1}{T_1^2} = \dfrac{T_1^2-T_2^2}{T_1^2T_2^2}
$$

The correct application of the Shomate equation would be:

$$
\begin{align}
S ^\circ  &= A \ln{(T)} + B(T) + \dfrac{C}{2}(T^2)\\ &+ \dfrac{D}{3}(T^3) - \dfrac{E}{2(T^2)} + G\\
\implies \Delta S ^\circ &= A \ln{\dfrac{T_2}{T_1}} + B(T_2-T_1) + \dfrac{C}{2}(T_2^2-T_1^2)\\
&+ \dfrac{D}{3}(T_2^3-T_1^3) - \dfrac{E}{2}\left( \dfrac{T_1^2-T_2^2}{T_1^2T_2^2}\right) + G
\end{align}
$$

> How to Calculate Entropy Changes at Non-Standard Conditions

Do note that conditions are still standard, and not non-standard, as indicated by the $\circ$ superscript in the above equations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ananta!  I am still slightly confused however.  If the Shomate equation is only applicable for standard conditions, how is it applicable to calculate the entropy change between two temperatures?  Thanks again.

Comment: @KarlNow yes! Temperature can change; however, pressure must be kept constant at $\pu{1 bar}$.

Comment: @KarlNow another factor to consider is the phase change of water. I am not sure if the Shomate equation is valid for liquid phase of water. I could help you out if you share your calculations as well.

Comment: After working through the problem I've figured out the issue now!  Thanks very much for all your help ananta!!

Comment: @KarlNow happy to help :)